# Javascript Sub Menus Overlap

Tags: javascript, css

The submenus seem to overlap if you select 'Work' then 'Contact' for example

http://www.ogormanconstruction.co.uk/home

Is there a way to only display the sub menu that has been selected using CSS and hiding the rest until otherwise clicked?

Can you use an example of how I would do this using the code provided:

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#menu').rb_menu({triggerEvent: 'click', hideOnLoad: true, loadHideDelay: 0, autoHide: false, transition: 'swing'});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#menu2').rb_menu({triggerEvent: 'click', hideOnLoad: true, loadHideDelay: 0, autoHide: false, transition: 'swing'});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#services').rb_menu({triggerEvent: 'click', hideOnLoad: true, loadHideDelay: 0, autoHide: false, transition: 'swing'});
});
</script>

<div id="menu" class="menu clearfix">
  <div class="toggle">Work</div>  
  <div class="items">  
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.ogormanconstruction.co.uk/basingstoke-treatment-works">Basingstoke Treatment Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Project Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Project Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Project Four</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Project Five</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Project Six</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="menu2" class="menu clearfix">
  <div class="toggle">Contact</div>  
  <div class="items">  
    <ul>
      <li>Mick O'Gorman<br /><a href="mailto:mick@ogormanconstruction.co.uk">mick@ogormanconstruction.co.uk</a><br />+44(0) 1234 567 890<br /><br />Barry O'Gorman<br /><a href="mailto:barry@ogormanconstruction.co.uk">barry@ogormanconstruction.co.uk</a><br />+44(0) 7515 569 086</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="services" class="menu clearfix">
  <div class="toggle">Services</div>  
  <div class="items">  
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.ogormanconstruction.co.uk/site-logistics">Site Logistics</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.ogormanconstruction.co.uk/waste-management">Waste Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.ogormanconstruction.co.uk/security-services">Security Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.ogormanconstruction.co.uk/traffic-management">Traffic Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.ogormanconstruction.co.uk/multi-service-gangs">Multi Service Gangs</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.ogormanconstruction.co.uk/facilities">Facilities & Accommodation</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.ogormanconstruction.co.uk/small-works-maintenance">Small Works & Maintenance</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.ogormanconstruction.co.uk/catering-services">Catering Services</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 435px;
    left: -15px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
}

#menu2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 445px;
    left: -15px;
    width: 60px;
}

#services {
    position: relative;
    top: 428px;
    left: -15px;
    width: 60px;
}

.menu .items a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu .items a {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #ABA099;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu .items {
    left: 180px;
    width: 250px !important;
}

.menu .items li {
    width: 250px;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #ABA099;
    height: 19px;
}   

.menu .items li a:hover {
    color: #4D4D4F;
}

.menu .toggle {
    color: #ABA099;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.menu .toggle-hover {
    color: #4D4D4F;
}
```

Comment: Where's the code for `rb_menu()`?

Comment: Have you tried setting autoHide to true?

Comment: that was all of the code I was provided with

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin is looking for other `.items` so it can hide them within the menu you are calling the plugin on, therefore it will probably work if you wrap all your menu's within 1 div and run `rb_menu()` on that. Eg:

```
$('#menu-wrapper').rb_menu({
    triggerEvent: 'click', 
    hideOnLoad: true, 
    loadHideDelay: 0, 
    autoHide: false, 
    transition: 'swing'
});
```

Comment: Yes, but you will have to also create that HTML element and ensure it wraps all the menus you wish to have the plugin applied too.

Comment: I've edited the code but I'm not sure that what I have done is correct

Comment: You need to wrap ALL of your menus in ONE wrapper - atm you have just wrapped each menu in another wrapper.